# Find a Specific String Value and Change by A Different One

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe

| category_groups_list | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Health Care | 10 |
| Financial Services,Lending and Investments | 15 |
| Real Estate | 5 |
| Financial Services | 20 |
| Financial Services,Professional Services | 25 |
| Financial Services,Real Estate | 10 |
| Administrative Services, Financial Services | 30 |

I want to find all the entries which include "Financial Services" and change the name by "Financial Services"

Output

| category_groups_list | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Health Care | 10 |
| Financial Services | 100 |
| Real Estate | 5 |

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to change to name of any column containing the string 'Financial Services', to be named 'Financial Services' and aggregate the Count of the renamed columns?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
mask = df["category_groups_list"].str.contains("Financial Services")

df.loc[mask, "category_groups_list"] = "Financial Services"

print(df.groupby("category_groups_list", as_index=False).sum())
```

Prints:

```
  category_groups_list  Count
0   Financial Services    100
1          Health Care     10
2          Real Estate      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.contains` to find the strings in `'category_groups_list'` that include `"Financial Services"`

```
filter = df['category_groups_list'].str.contains("Financial Services")
total = df[filter]['Count'].sum()
```

Then remove the entries that have been grouped

```
df2 = df[~filter]
```

Finally, add the entry for `Financial Services`

```
df3 = df2.append({"category_groups_list": "Financial Services", "Count": total}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the cells of the dataframe (df). Check if under the specified column the cell contains the string you are looking for. If it does, update it to the new string:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if 'Financial Services' in row['category_groups_list']:
        df.at[index, 'category_groups_list'] = "Financial Service"'
```

To aggregate all rows with equal cells under the specified column:

```
df = df.groupby('category_groups_list').sum().reset_index()
```

This method is easily adaptable to other occurrences of similar situations.